# Powerbi: remove part of the string value in column and put it to another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, data-cleaning

I have values in powerbi column with prefix e.g. Title: some title.
I want to put this column to another table using dax, but without prefix "Title: " so it should be "some title".

In source table values can contain this prefix but there could be some values that do not have it.

| Old column | new column |
| --- | --- |
| Title: some title | some title |
| Title: sky | sky |
| Apple | Apple |
| Title: xxx Title | xxx Title |

Comment: Adding sample date would be more helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: Please supply your expected results too.

Comment: Added a tabular format data or snip it and added it, the given data does not make any sense

Comment: Why are you doing this in DAX and not Power Query?

Comment: I use new column functionalty from powerbi, I thought it uses dax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create a calculated table :

```
Attempt = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    TitleTable,
    "Old Column", [Old Column],  
    "New Column",                
    IF(
        FIND("Title: ", [Old Column], 1, LEN([Old Column]) + 1) = 1,
        TRIM(MID([Old Column], LEN("Title: ") + 1, LEN([Old Column]))),
        [Old Column]
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should do this in PQ but here is a DAX solution:

```
Column = 
VAR x = SEARCH("Title: ", 'Table'[Old column], , 0)
RETURN IF(x>0,  MID('Table'[Old column], 8, LEN('Table'[Old column])), 'Table'[Old column])
```

[image]

Comment: Oo I did not know I can. Can you write me how?

Comment: Might be best to ask a new question specifying Power Query answers instead.